# Get event target name (not value) from React Bootstrap Form?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I have a React Bootstrap Form component

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms

I just need to be able to get the name/ref of the input box that the user is typing inside so I can update the state dynamically. I did this already with the standard Form using:

```
this.setState({
           [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
```

but I wanted to use React's Bootstrap form. I can already get the value of the Form input, but I can't find a way to get its reference name (like if the input box is for dealerName, I am unable to get the string `'dealerName'` so I can update it dynamically instead of having to hardcode the state property name to a value to update it) so I can dynamically update the state. Without  that, I would have to create multiple separate functions for all the different forms I have.

This is my sample React Bootstrap **Form**:

```
    <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formDealersAdd">
          <Form.Label>userId:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="userId" ref={this.userId} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
          <Form.Label>dealerName:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="dealerName" ref={this.dealerName} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          <Form.Label>dealer id:</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text"  placeholder={did} ref={this.did} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" onClick={this.handleDealersAddFormClick}>SUBMIT</Button>{' '}
          </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

My **constructor** looks like this:

```
    class App extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.userId= React.createRef();
        this.dealerName = React.createRef();
        this.did = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
          userId: '',
          dealerName: '',
          did: '',
        };
      }
    }
```

And my **handleInputChange** function:

```
    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

   // manually hardcoding it like this causes issues and makes my code bad
         this.setState({
          userId: this.userId.current.value,
          dealerName: this.dealerName.current.value,
          did: this.did.current.value
        })
      }
```

I was originally handling the inputChange by simply setting the state with

```
    this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
```

and this worked fine for the standard Form (non-React Boostrap form) and it does return the correct value for the input that is being actively updated/being typed inside by a user, but  **event.target.name does not work.**

Thus, as you can see above, I just manually hardcoded the values to be updated inside the **state** object, but this is messy and causes error when the user clicks to see a new Form on my website and the properties are null and the state tries to update so it crashes.

Is there a way to update my state properties for the inputs of the React Bootstrap form similar to how I used [event.target.name] : event.target.value for the regular Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `get its reference name`, add values to the props `name` would be fine

Before:

```
<Form.Control type="text" placeholder="userId" ref={this.userId} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
```

After:

```
<Form.Control type="text" name="userId" placeholder="userId" ref={this.userId} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
```

Comment: Doh. I had this in there, and it wasn't working (so i thought) but its definitely working now. smh im dumb thx